# When is boost::asio::error::no_buffer_space thrown?

Tags: c++, boost

I have an application that leverages boost::asio to accept new connections. The application uses async_accept to take anything and further process. However, I notice that in certain instance types, I'm consistently running into boost::asio::error::no_buffer_space while accepting new connections. Under which circumstances is this thrown?

I've tried the following so far:

1. Increasing the listen backlog for the application. This is shown to take affect after `ss -ntlp` which shown the new backlog size.
2. Increasing `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog`
3. Increasing `net.core.somaxconn`

Nonetheless, I'm consistently getting boost::asio::error::no_buffer_space thrown while trying to accept a burst of connections. Under what additional circumstances would I get this, and how can I possibly mitigate it? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell Asio only ever throws this as a result of connect, getnameinfo emulation or io_uring implementation. Since you claim it happens from just accepting connections, I'd google for `ENOBUF` which is the corresponding POSIX error code.

Comment: (Alternatively, post a minimal self-contained reproducer, perhaps mentioning platform and versions tested)